# Calculating block statistics from land cover raster using R?

Tags: raster, r, land-cover, land-use

I have a raster (5 x 5 m resolution) representing land cover. Each cell contains a integer value (from 1 to 10) representing a total of ten land cover classes (e.g. 1-forest; 2-agricultural areas; 3-urban areas;(...)10-scrublands).

From this land cover raster, I would like to generate 10 rasters with a resolution of 10 x 10 m representing the proportion of each land cover class per cell. In another words, I would like to produce a raster representing the proportion of forest per cell, another raster representing the proportion of agricultural areas per cell, etc... (please see the figure below that shows what I want to accomplish).

[image]

I know this task can be accomplished in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst by generating 10 binary rasters (1- presence of a specific land use class; 0-absence of a specific land use class) and then using the "Block statistics" option. However, because I do not hold a license for ArcGIS, this is not a valid option.

Instead, I would like to know how to do this in R (version 3.40). I have checked previous posts and I managed to find one where an user intended to do something similar ([Calculating Proportion of Land Cover Classes with moving window around point in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236337)). However, I do not want to calculate proportion of land cover with a moving window.

Below find the code to generate a dummy RasterLayer object with five land cover classes coded as integers.

```
    r<-raster(ncols=100, nrows=100,xmn=100,xmx=1100,ymn=0,ymx=1000, crs="+proj=lcc +lat_1=35 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4000000 +y_0=2800000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")

    x<-0:5

    r[]<-sample(x,10000,replace=T)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `aggregate` function in the `raster` package to do this. For example, to produce a raster at half the resolution of the original, showing the proportion of cells covered with land class `1`:

```
aggregate(r, fact=2, fun=function(vals, na.rm) {
  sum(vals==1, na.rm=na.rm)/length(vals)
})
```

To do this for all land classes:

```
cov_pct <- lapply(unique(r), function(land_class) {
             aggregate(r, fact=2, fun=function(vals, na.rm) {
               sum(vals==land_class, na.rm=na.rm)/length(vals)
             })
           })
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree that `raster::aggregate()` works well in most cases, especially when a user-defined function is involved as in the answer given by @dbaston. However, you might want to have a look at the **velox** package as an alternative approach that comes in particularly handy when dealing with larger rasters.

The only caveat here is that `VeloxRaster_aggregate()` accepts "standard" aggregate functions (ie. `c("sum", "mean", "min", "max", "median")` only –
 any work steps beyond that level need to be carried out beforehand. Nevertheless, the resulting speed gain surely justifies the need for a little more code. In the example below, I increased the `ncell()` of your input raster by a factor of 100 and compared runtimes. As seen from the benchmark results, **velox** outperforms the `raster::aggregate()` based approach by a factor of 13, on average, when fed with the larger raster image.

```
library(raster)

r = raster(ncols = 1e3, nrows = 1e3
           , xmn = 100, xmx = 1100, ymn = 0, ymx = 1000
           , crs="+proj=lcc +lat_1=35 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4000000 +y_0=2800000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")

x = 0:5
set.seed(123) # make sampling reproducible
r[] <- sample(x, 1e6, replace = TRUE)


### benchmark ----

library(microbenchmark)
library(velox)

microbenchmark(

  ## raster approach
  rasterAgg = {
    lst1 = lapply(unique(r), function(land_class) {
      aggregate(r, fact = 2, fun = function(vals, na.rm) {
        sum(vals == land_class, na.rm = na.rm)/length(vals)
      })
    })
  }

  ## velox approach
  , veloxAgg = {
    vls = r[]

    lst2 = lapply(unique(r), function(i) {
      # set the current land cover class to 1, everything else to 0
      ids = (vls == i)
      vls[ids] = 1; vls[!ids] = 0
      rst = setValues(r, vls)

      # create velox raster and aggregate
      vlx = velox(rst)
      vlx$aggregate(factor = 2, aggtype = "mean")
      vlx$as.RasterLayer()
    })
  }

  ## repeat every chunk n times
  , times = 10)
```

And here are the benchmark results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
rasterAgg 5844.2713 5950.7560 6140.8879 6186.1065 6354.8678 6370.6968    10   b
veloxAgg   319.2344  336.5698  472.3171  375.2693  622.2361  744.8573    10  a
```

You can also `plot()` or subtract the single output layers in `lst1` and `lst2` from each other in order to verify that the two approaches create identical results.

As a reference: using your original 1e4 pixels raster as input, `VeloxRaster_aggregate()` performs *only* 4 times faster on my machine (at least on my machine), which leads me to the conclusion that the **raster** based approach is absolutely suitable for smaller images. However, **velox** is definitely worth a deeper look when dealing with larger datasets that still fit well into memory.

Comment: `velox` is useful for medium-size rasters but fails for truly large rasters where everything can't be loaded into memory at once.

Comment: Right, same like using `raster::as.matrix()` on a truly large raster. It all comes down to the amount of memory available.