# Convert discrete data (e.g. geological units) to percentage within pixel?

Tags: qgis, raster, r, rasterization

I am looking for a way to convert discrete data in a way that they can be used in ecological niche models.  I try to avoid factor data so I thought about transforming the data to %.

I have a shapefile with geological units. I'd like to convert specific units (eg. limestone) to rasters representing the percentage of the respective unit within each pixel. My intention is to use this as an environmental variable in species distribution models.
[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297908/calculating-block-statistics-from-land-cover-raster-using-r) is a similar question I found. However, this results in sharp transition zones. I am wondering if there might be other ways of doing things like that?

I also tried a mooving window approach with `focal()` in `R` to smooth the transition a little bit. Additionally, this would give bigger units more "weight" compared to very small isolated ones. This, however,  sometimes results in strange artefacts caused by the window.

Another approach could be to convert the resulting `raster` from the "aggregate" solution (see link) to a `data.frame` and use it as input for an interpolation.

What do you think, how could a general workflow look like?

I am working with R and QGIS.

**EDIT:**

Here are some maps for visualisation.

original shapefile (blue is limestone)
[image]

shp rasterized to 10 m and % within 50 m spatial resolution. The values are in %. The transition zone is sharp.

[image]

shp rasterized to 50 m spatial resolution and smoothed with mooving window (89*99 pixel). The values are in %, the transition zone is smoothened. However the shape of the mooving window ist visible.

[image]

Nearest neighbour interpolation (10 neighbour pixel)
[image]

Inverse distance interpolation (IDW) Power:2
[image]

Comment: How big are your raster cells going to be compared to the size of your shapefile features? Can you show some typical maps? Its unusual to have spatial features small compared to the raster size, so that mostly the cells are 100% or 0% of a category except along the edges, and often that can be neglected...

Comment: The final raster resolution is 50 m. The size of the features is varying between smaller than 1 km and several km. I will add some maps I have produced.

Comment: The `exactextractr` package does this directly: https://isciences.gitlab.io/exactextractr/reference/coverage_fraction.html

Comment: @dbaston: thx I'll try it out

Comment: it calculates the percentages for every single feature separately.

Comment: combine your units of the same type into a single feature?

Comment: I'd caution you on doing this for an SDM. You are making some big assumptions when transforming this categorical data to continuous. This can result in spurious model results.